# How to bring UAC's consent.exe to the foreground programmatically?

Tags: c#, uac

**How to (if at all possible) bring the Vista/Win7 UAC consent dialog to the foreground, when it is minimized in the taskbar?**

For instance, consider the following scenario:
My application checks for updates during startup, it downloads the new update file and it executes it by providing the administrator's password in the Process.StartInfo, after that my application closes.

At this point, if the user or Windows itself manages to lose focus from the MSI installer window (perhaps by clicking on the desktop or another window), UAC sees that installer window is not the foreground window and thus pops a blinking consent dialog into the taskbar.

Some not so brightminded customers don't understand that my application hasn't yet finished updating and try to relaunch the application. At this stage, I can enumerate the running processes and find the consent.exe which is blinking in the taskbar.

The problem is I can't bring it to the foreground. I tried to invoke ShowWindow() from user32.dll with different paramaters (restore, show, normal), but nothing happens. I did check the process MainWindowHandle and it seems ok (it isn't zero or negative). I'm guessing that the problem lies with UAC creating a different desktop session for the consent dialog (secure desktop).

If the user can click the blinking icon in the taskbar to bring the consent dialog to the foreground, then it should also be possible to simulate this via code?

PS! I'm using C#

Comment: That has got to be my #1 UAC pet peeve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try [SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ? Also, in native win32 there is not really anything called a main window, a process can have 0 or any number of "main windows" but in the case of consent.exe, I'm guessing it has just one...

**Edit:**

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd,LPARAM lParam) 
{
    char buf[50];
    *buf=0;
    GetClassName(hwnd,buf,50);
    buf[sizeof("$$$Secure UAP")-1]=0;
    if (!lstrcmp("$$$Secure UAP",buf)) 
    {
        SwitchToThisWindow(hwnd,true);
    }
    return true;
}
...
EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc,0);
```

This will switch to the secure desktop, but I would not recommend using this because:

- It uses the undocumented $$$Secure UAP... window class
- Using SwitchToThisWindow is evil, you should never switch focus when the user does not want to
- If more than one UAC confirmation dialog is active, you can't be sure which consent.exe you will be switching to

The problem is that the consent window is not a owned popup, if it was you could be sure you got the correct HWND. Hopefully Win8 will have consent act as a owned popup, or even better, a modal dialog.

Comment: SetForegroundWindow is only a suggestion, one usually ignored on Vista and Seven, both of which have UAC. It should flash the taskbar button, assuming there is a taskbar button.

Comment: @Tergiver: Well, what SetForegroundWindow depends on if you are in the foreground or not, if you are you can bring any window to the front, if not, all it does is flash the taskbar, but it is your best option unless you use horrible hacks to hijack the foucs and piss off your users

Comment: @Anders: Right, but the OPs problem is that their window isn't foreground, so SetForegroundWindow isn't going to help.

Comment: @Tergiver: It seems to me that he would have foreground lock in the case of "Some not so brightminded customers don't understand that my application hasn't yet finished updating and try to relaunch the application"

Comment: Tried SetForegroundWindow, does not work. Also, my understanding is that SetForegroundWindow only works if the window is shown (not minimized). Thus if a window is minimized, you first need to call ShowWindow, then you can call SetForegroundWindow. But as I said, even ShowWindow does not work in my case...  @Anders - you are wrong. When the customer relaunches my application, then that application will be in the foreground. At that point I'd like to bring to the foreground the blinking consent.exe, but I think it's technically not possible, because it's on another (secure) desktop.

Comment: @Marko: How am I wrong, if your application is in the foreground then you have the right to call SetForegroundWindow on a window in a different process also (While the consent ui is displayed on a different desktop, the taskbar button is on your desktop and it does not switch to the secure desktop until it gets focus)

Comment: You are wrong because of your statement - "OPs problem is that their window isn't foreground". My application window is in the foreground. Secondly, I know that if my application is in the foreground I can bring other windows to the foreground etc. But the problem is, that for some reasone those rules don't apply to consent.exe, thus my question. How do I bring it to the foreground programaticaly? Neither ShowWindow() or SetForegroundWindow() work, and I don't know of another way to bring a window to the foreground...

Comment: Aah, sorry about that. Was looking at @Anders and for some reason thought that was the person writing. Instead that text was targeted at you... (I don't think I can edit my previous comments, so just to state the fact - Tergiver's statement is wrong)

Comment: I didn't test your code, but I'll accept it as an answer, since it seems that no other answers are coming. Also it seems plausible. I won't bother using this code because it's unsafe c# (uses pointers), also because of undocumented API. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion here that may help you: [How do you maximize User Account control(UAC) window?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-you-maximize-user-account-controluac-window/b5c96c91-08a6-4c8c-8c7a-571ed5ea74b4)

The official documentation about that subject is here: [Redesign for UAC Compatibility (UAC)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756922.aspx)

Comment: The links you gave talked about applications having improper HWND, which is why UAC goes to the taskbar. The problem I have is the HWNDs are correct, simply the installer loses focus, that's why UAC goes to the taskbar. That is not a problem per se, but I want to programatically bring it to the foreground, when the user tries to relaunch my application...